# application(_:url:options:) is never called

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project with default settings in Xcode 11: Single View App / Swift / Storyboards.
2. Add your Document Types and Imported UTIs.

Result: My application appears in “Copy to...” menu (or “Open in...” if we use `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`).
It really launches the app.
But this delegate method: [`application(_:url:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application) is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 13 this method was replaced with a new [UISceneDelegate
 method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene) by default.

Solution:

If you don't need scenes, just remove all scene-related code: `SceneDelegate` etc., remove `UIApplicationSceneManifest` from **Info.plist**, and add `var window: UIWindow?` to your `AppDelegate`.

`application(_:url:options:)` is working now.

Comment: Or instead of removing scenes you could of course use the UISceneDelegate method.